# Looking for a set based on random pieces with grey marble texture plastic

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

My son received three, gallon-sized, ziplock bags full of random LEGO's for Christmas. I've been scanning the interwebs for unique pieces in hopes of finding some of the kits and instructions for some of the more interesting (to me) pieces. I've been searching all over and hope to find some direction in this forum. I've attached a picture of some of the pieces which look to be part of a spaceship, maybe. Also, there are some numbers stamped on the inside of a few of them such as AM72433, AM18902, and AM76367. I've searched for these piece numbers as well but I can't seem to track them down.
[image]

Comment: That isn't actual lego - on the circular piece where you can see the studs, there is no "LEGO" on each stud - they are smooth. What you have is likely one of many knock-off brands.

Comment: First, thanks for the quick response! Second, I feel like a dummy. I should have noticed that there are no LEGO stamps on these pieces. I'll try to cull them out and move forward with more promising pieces!

Comment: Plus, would you realy think that a lego piece would be shaped like that? (No offense)

Answer (score 6):

X-27's comment is correct, I have 40 years of LEGO collecting under my belt, and I have never seen any bricks with a speckle pattern like that.

You might go through the bricks you got, knock off bricks are very easy to spot once you have seen a few. Cheap looking plastic, dull colors, lack of Lego logos (almost every single part Lego makes is stamped somewhere) are all signs of knock-off brands.

If you want to search for sets based off of real Lego parts, try: https://brickset.com/, they have a part catalog of pretty much every set ever made that you can use to look stuff up.

Here is a random part I pulled up to show you: https://brickset.com/parts/74335/mini-antenna-ass-red-bla

Comment: Thank you, both, for the quick response and resource for finding bricks to actual LEGO sets! Have a great holiday weekend!